# Accessing Gmail From Terminal

Tags: terminal, gmail, smtp

Is there a way to access my Gmail smtp account  just using the terminal or is this not possible? I saw this link but it did not help:

https://medium.com/@stessyco/gmail-from-the-command-line-with-mutt-mac-os-x-92d047bcd74f

What specifically didn't work was the configuration file. I edited it with my gmail specs as stated in the tutorial, but when I ran it, nothing happened.

Comment: Hi Cody, I'm not sure you have tried enough or made enough research about the question you are asking. As said in my answer, the link you provide us is a good tuto and should work. If it didn't, you need to provide more informations than "it did not help". Which step failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure that by "access my Gmail smtp account just using the terminal" you mean "Using a command line program in the terminal" :)

I personally don't use Mutt and don't know the program. However, it is one of the best command line email client.

Everything seems to be well explained on the webpage you provide via the link

I'm using alpine (same concept). Here is a tuto: [How to set Alpine and gmail](http://8bitbatty.com/post/pine-lives-using-alpine-with-gmail/)

Comment: Your link for "Setting_up_Pine_(Alpine)_for_IMAP_Gmail" is dead.

Comment: The link has been updated. It is not the same tuto, but the content is almost identical.